# Laravel relationship attach fails in PestPHP test but works in PHPUnit test

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, contains

I have two Laravel models - `Company` and `User` - with a pivot table between them. The pivot has a `role` attribute.

The problem I'm having is `$company->users->contains($user)` always returns true - even on a refreshed (ie empty) database.

**Details**

In `Company.php`:

```php
public function users(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('role')->withTimestamps();
}
```

In `User.php`:

```php
public function companies(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class)->withPivot('role')->withTimestamps();
}
```

I completely refresh the database using `php artisan migrate:fresh` and confirm by inspecting the database.

Then in Tinker:

```php
$user = User::factory()->create();
$company = Company::factory()->create();
print_r($company->users->contains($user)); // true
echo $company->users->count(); // 0
```

**Edit - factories**

Both factories are standard - the user factory is unedited from the initial installation, the company factory just uses faker to set a `name` attribute.

Comment: Maybe the factory definition does something weird

Comment: @IGP - thanks for your suggestion. The user factory is the default out-of-the-box, the company one is similar. Both just use faker to set attributes, nothing else.

Comment: Do you get a different result if you dump `$company->users->contains(fn($model) => $model->is($user))` ?

Comment: Can we see the factories?